# Security Group of AWS Load Balancer does not forward traffic to backend instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, load-balancing, security-groups

Before I created the new security group (id `sg-abcdefg`), I am able to reach the load balance from the IP address 107.178.195.144 via http. The load balancer will then forward the traffic to the backend instances. The backend instances have only one security group which allows inbound traffic from the loadbalancer group.

I want to whitelist a range of address to limit inbound traffic to the load balancer itself in AWS. Currently it is open to the world. I added inbound rules to a new security group this way

```
 aws ec2 authorize-security-group-ingress --group-id sg-abcdefg --protocol tcp --port 80 --cidr 107.178.192.0/18
```

It is the final result:

[image]

However, after adding the new security group, all the traffic from `107.178.195.144` via loadbalancer to the backend instances are blocked.

- I double checked and am sure that 107.178.195.144 is in the range of 107.178.192.0/18
- I have added the new security group (`sg-abcdefg`) to the backend instances too but it did not help.

Did I miss anything in my setup?

**EDIT**

It seems like the root cause is the backend instances stop receiving the health check ping. I have added `174.12.0.0/16` (the IP range of the subnet) to the sec group but to no avail

Comment: I haven't tried this but  `--port` should be a port number? Also you said in your question that you are able to talk to ELB via HTTP and in the command you are specifying https.

Comment: I have updated the question. I should be number 80 as you pointed out

Comment: What do the security group(s) for the backend instances look like, in terms of inbound rules/ACLs?